# What does -0 mean in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

I was writing an algorithm in C/++ and when I was debugging using a print statement (very professional, I know), I saw an odd value: `-0`. Does this mean the same thing as a regular 0 or could this cause bugs? If so, how can I fix those bugs?

Comment: IEEE-754 also has different representations for +0 and -0. But then again, it is not based on 2's complement. That would be your `float`, `double` and `long double`.

Comment: I would like to see the declaration of the variable holding the value and also the code of the print statement that produces this value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both languages `-0` is the unary negation of the `int` constant / literal `0`.

If your `int` is 2's complement (most likely in C, and must be from C++20), then it's exactly the same as `0`, and no sane formatter would ever print `-0` for `0`.

If your `int` is 1's complement or signed magnitude then `-0` is a *signed negative zero*. It will compare numerically equal to 0 but its bit pattern *will* be different.

You can convert a signed negative zero to a zero by adding zero!

Most likely, your print statement is outputting a slightly negative floating point value, which your formatting is rounding towards zero and therefore you have nothing really to worry about.

Comment: [sign-magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) also contains a negative 0